# python file I/O and arithmetic calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have five text files each of 7 columns by 9 rows as follows:

```
file_one = 'C:/test/1.txt'
file_two = 'C:/test/2.txt' 
. . . 
file_five = 'C:/test/5.txt'
```

In order to calculate the following things using Python language:

- Mean of first row for each file, if mean of first column of each file is 50
- Mean of second row for each file, if mean of first column of each file is 51
- Mean of third row for each file, if mean of first column of each file is 52

First of all, how to obtain the list of files correcting the code below?

```
import glob 
file_list = glob.glob('C:/test/*.txt') 
out_file = open('C:/test/out_file/out_file.txt', 'w') 
for i in file_list: 
    out_file.write(i) 
out_file.close ()
```

Comment: "I would learn easily if some one could write me a simple code for that purpose." Sorry, that's not our job. Have a go yourself, and if you get into any trouble, then feel free to ask us a question on what you have trouble on, showing us the code you have tried.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Most of all, **do not** create 100 numbered variables. Use a list. `filenames = ['C:\\one.txt', 'C:\\two.txt', ..., 'C:\\hundred.txt']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to do this wouldnt be that simple
You would need to

- Make a list of the files
- read and parse through the files to get the first line
- find the mean of the first line
- if that mean is 50 get the second row and find the average

and so on

So the code wont really be something you can just write up real quick you will need functions and if statements and something to read the files and pic out what you want and im sure youre capable of doing all those things if you know basic python

Good Luck!